# websvn geshi error on large files

Tags: php, websvn, geshi

I use websvn with (default on) geshi colourise option. If I want to open (not so) large files like wordpress db class file (`wp-db.php`) the browser throws error:`101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)` error. With smaller files it works fine.

If I turn off geshi in websvn config, there is no problems with large files. No problem opening files 2-3 times bigger than wp-db.php. But I have no colourising.

I think it's some php config problem. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

There's some rather large regexps in geshi that may trigger this. I have an old note saying 'delete some stars from SCRIPT_DELIMITERS in php-brief.php'.

YMMV, of course.